# How to protect swagger documentation with password

Tags: python, flask, swagger, flask-restplus

I am building a flask app and need to add password for swagger documentation in production, but dont know how. Here is my code:

```py
api = Api(
    version='1.0',
    title='API',
    description='Main API',
    doc='/doc',
    authorizations=authorizations)
...
api.init_app(app)
```

This documentation shouldnt be public for anyone to see, right? but i cant find a way to add password to it. Any suggestion would be awsome.

Comment: Protect the endpoint by requiring SSO ?

Comment: @AK47 Yes, For example i can use HTTP Basic Authentication, but dont know how.

Comment: The API itself should definitely be secured - if not, that's your priority. I don't think you  necessarily need to protect the API documentation - unless you think it's a particularly special design and forms IP or you're worried the API might not actually be secure (in which case you're hoping for security by obscurity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know its very late, but still.

```
class MyApi(Api):
    def render_doc(self):
        view = super().render_doc()
        if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.has_role('admin'):
            return view
        return redirect(url_for('security.login', next=request.url))
```

You need to modify this method which returns end view function.